# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

Tags: python, sequence, typeerror, odeint

i have the following three modules my first one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import math
import beginvalues as bv


def func(lijst,t):
    x = lijst[0]
    y = lijst[1]
    z = lijst[2]

    G = 6,67e-14
    MBH = 9,94e38
    N = 1 + x**2 + y**2/bv.a**2 + z**2/bv.b**2
    NT = (1e-3 + x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**(3/2)

    a_x = -(220**2)*x/N - (G * MBH * x)/NT
    a_y = -(220**2)*y/(N*bv.a**2) - (G * MBH * y )/NT
    a_z = -(220**2)*z/(N*bv.b**2) - (G * MBH * z )/NT
    return [lijst[3],lijst[4],lijst[5],a_x,a_y,a_z]
```

my second one:

```
import numpy as np


# Ingeven van de parameterwaarden a en b. Indien deze niet relevant zijn, wordt een melding gegeven. 
tekst = "Geef waarden in voor a en b, waarbij 1>a>b:"
print tekst
a= float(input("Geef een waarde in voor a: "))
b= float(input("Geef een waarde in voor b: "))


if b<(a/(1+a**2)**(0.5)) or b>a:
    print " Dit zijn geen goede waarden voor a en b. \n Het model is niet fysisch relevant. \n Gelieve andere waarden te kiezen."



# Ingeven van de beginvoorwaarden.
# We maken een array aan waarin de beginwaarden geplaatst worden.

begin_x = 1
begin_y = 1
begin_z = 1
v0_x=1
v0_y=1
v0_z=1
init_val = [begin_x,begin_y,begin_z,v0_x,v0_y,v0_z]
```

and my third one:

```
import bvgzwartgat as bvg
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import beginvalues as bv


# We voeren een tijdsintegratie door van 0 tot 13*10^9 in 10000 stappen.
# De beginvoorwaarden worden geinitialiseerd in de module "beginvalues".
# TIJDSEENHEID?????????????????? kpc/km/s = 978 10^6 jaar
t=np.linspace(0,15,10000)
I=odeint(bvg.func,bv.init_val,t)




# 2d plotjes 
X=[]
Y=[]
Z=[]
for i in range(len(I)):
    kolom = I[i]
    X.append(kolom[0])
    Y.append(kolom[1])
    Z.append(kolom[2])



plt.figure("x-y projectie")
plt.plot(X,Y)

plt.figure("x-z projectie")
plt.plot(X,Z)

plt.figure("y-z projectie")
plt.plot(Y,Z)
plt.show( )
```

Now i get the following error when trying to run the program from the main module the third one : 
in func
    a_x = -(220**2)*x/N - (G * MBH * x)/NT
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

So i think the programs thinks a_x is a tuple, what i'm trying to do here is calculate 
the a_x,a_y and a_z with starting values init_val with odeint.

This code has worked perfectly before without the (G*MBH*x)/NT part in a_x 
So i think we have to figure out why the program thinks a_x is a sequence.

Comment: This is something easy to troubleshoot, which is far more instructive than an answer here. Wrap your line that's throwing an error in a `try` block and `except TypeError`. In the `except` block write out a descriptive `print` statement. `"x is {}\nN is {}\nG is {}\nMBH is {}\nNT is {}".format(x,N,G,MBH,NT)` or etc

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it looks like you are assigning G and E numerical values like '6,67e-14'. If that is the case don't use commas in your integer representation

Comment: Which is to say, Python's floating-point literals are not locale-dependent: you must use `6.67e-14`. The expression `6,67e-14` is evaluated as a tuple consisting of `6` and `67e-14`.